# Tex Studio: fontspec.sty not found

Tags: texstudio

I'm new to LaTeX. I downloaded a project I'd been working on at overleaf to try to get it running offline.

However in Tex Studio I get the following error in the cls file:

```
File `textpos.sty` not found. \RequirePackage.
```

From what I've read I can download the file and place it in the directory but how do I install textpos so that it's available system wide?

Comment: Have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te It's older, but probably still relevant.